# Из переменной надо разбить цифры в разные переменные

Tags: python

В прогу попадает длинное число, мне нужно что бы каждая цифра из данной переменной ушла в свою переменную. Например в коде ниже число '1561108032002' то есть в переменную a1 попадет '111' и тд. Думаю это можно сделать как-то через списки, но не могу допереть. Буду очень благодарен если поможете .

```
a = 1561108032002
a1 = ''
a2 = ''
a3 = ''
a4 = ''
a5 = ''
a6 = ''
a7 = ''
a8 = ''
a9 = ''

for i in list(str(a)):
    if i == '1':
        a1 += i
    elif i == '2':
        a2 += i
    elif i == '3':
        a3 += i
    elif i == '4':
        a4 += i
    elif i == '5':
        a5 += i
    elif i == '6':
        a6 += i
    elif i == '7':
        a7 += i
    elif i == '8':
        a8 += i
    elif i == '9':
        a9 += i
print(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9)
#Вывод: 111 22 3  5 6  8
```

Comment: *можно сделать как-то через списки* - можно поместить в список, в массив... зачем отдельные переменные? Задача конечная какая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевести в строку, отсортировать, собрать в группы, группы собрать в строки:

```
import itertools

n = 1561108032002
a = [''.join(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(str(n)))]
print(a)
```

> ```
> ['0000', '111', '22', '3', '5', '6', '8']
> ```

Если вы хотите учесть так же отсутствующие цифры, то решение немного другое, в чём-то даже проще:

```
n = 1561108032002
s = str(n)
a = [d * s.count(d) for d in '0123456789']
print(a)
```

> ```
> ['0000', '111', '22', '3', '', '5', '6', '', '8', '']
> ```

Если вас беспокоят десять проходов по строке, то можно в один проход. Хотя лично предпочитаю предыдущий более компактный код:

```
n = 1561108032002
counters = [0] * 10
for d in str(n):
    counters[int(d)] += 1
a = [str(d) * c for d, c in enumerate(counters)]
print(a)
```

> ```
> ['0000', '111', '22', '3', '', '5', '6', '', '8', '']
> ```

Для подсчёта элементов контейнера создан [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

n = 1561108032002
c = collections.Counter(str(n))
a = [d * c[d] for d in '0123456789']
print(a)
```

> ```
> ['0000', '111', '22', '3', '', '5', '6', '', '8', '']
> ```

С ним же версия без нулевых счётчиков:

```
import collections

n = 1561108032002
a = sorted(d * c for d, c in collections.Counter(str(n)).items())
print(a)
```

> ```
> ['0000', '111', '22', '3', '5', '6', '8']
> ```

Comment: Станислав, спасибо за внимательность, удалил свой ответ. Я не обратил внимание, что нужно не числа, а строки получать.  И да, тернарный оператор был тоже лишним:-)

Comment: @Сергей, зря удалили. Ваш вариант был единственный, который не использовал `str(n)` - иногда бывает полезно. А поправить результат с чисел на строки было не сложно. Я бы восстановил и привёл в порядок.

Comment: Станислав, спасибо за доброжелательность. Я восстановил ответ, тем более, что вспомнил, почему я на нули не обращал внимания  - потому, что автору они и не нужны. См.также ответ под вопросом.

Answer (score 2):

Если именно с переменными, то можно через словарь:

```
a = 124419149

vars = {'1': '', '2': '', '3': '', '4': '', '5': '', '6': '', '7': '', '8': '', '9': ''}

for i in str(a):
    vars[i] += i
    
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9 = vars.values()

print(a1)
print(a9)
print(a4)

# вывод: 111
# 99
# 444
```

Answer (score 1):

Всегда, когда у вас возникает желание использовать много переменных, отдайте предпочтение [массивам](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp)

В этом алгоритме в [словарь](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) в ключи добавляются уникальные числа, а к значению конкатенируется это же число. После чего значения [словаря](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) преобразуется в [список](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)

```
num = 1561108032002;

dict = {};
for n in str(num):
    try:
        dict[n] += n;
    except:
        dict[n] = n;

result = list(dict.values());

print(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо десяти не очень удобных переменных **используем список, как вы и хотели** (хотя можно и в них переписать из списка в самом конце).
Каждое число окажется в ячейке со своим номером.
Поясняющие комментарии даны по тексту.

Вариант 1 (основной) - использует факт, что нули не надо считать (в примере вывода в вопросе нули не выводятся). Со строками вообще не работаем -только с числами.

```
a = 1561108032002
# Заполняем список нулями изначально
counters = [0]*10
# Уменьшаем число на одну цифру за каждый проход по циклу, пока не станет число нулем
while a:
    # Получаем последнюю цифру делением по модулю
    digit = a % 10
    # Уменьшаем число на последнюю цифру целочисленным делением
    a = a // 10
    # Увеличиваем цифру на 10 и добавляем ещё одну цифру
    counters[digit] = counters[digit] * 10 + digit
# Печатаем получившиеся числа, если они не равны 0
for i in range (10):
    if counters[i]:
        print (counters[i], end =' ')
```

Вариант 2 (запасной) - на случай, если надо и нули сосчитать. Разница с основным: список заполняем пустыми строками, а не нулями, сохраняем цифры в виде символов в списке, печатаем всё.

```
a = 1561108032002
# Заполняем список пустыми строками изначально
counters = [''] * 10
# Уменьшаем число на одну цифру за каждый проход по циклу, пока не станет число нулем
while a:
    # Получаем последнюю цифру делением по модулю
    digit = a % 10
    # Уменьшаем число на последнюю цифру целочисленным делением
    a = a // 10
    # Добавляем ещё одну цифру
    counters[digit] = counters[digit] + str(digit)
# Печатаем все получившиеся строки
for i in range (10):
    print (counters[i], end =' ')
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо за внимательность. В примере автора нули не выводятся, хоть в тестовой входной последовательности они есть, поэтому основной вариант не занимается нулями. Добавил резервный вариант с отображением нулей. И убрал излишество с тернарным оператором - тоже спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один вариант на основе списков

```py
a = 1561108032002

nums = [''] * 10
for val in str(a):
     nums[int(val)] += val
print(''.join(nums))  # 0000111223568
```

Comment: Последний `join` не нужен. У вас получился сортированный список цифр, который можно получить проще: `''.join(sorted(str(a)))`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, Вы правы, ‘join’ тут не нужен, он просто чтобы показать, что получается в итоге, а так элементы нужно получать по индексу

Answer (score 0):

```
spisok = []
a = 1561108032002
b = str(a)
for i in range(len(b)):
    spisok.append(b[i])
spisok = list(set(spisok))
for i in range(len(spisok)):
    print(spisok[i])
```

Comment: а ничего, что это вообще не печатает то, что автор вопроса хочет?

Comment: @Сергей Вы про то, что нужно ```print(spisok[i], end=" ")``` или про что? Автор сам сказал про списки, я привёл пример

Comment: Автор просил разбить число на одинаковые цифры. Ваш код просто выводит каждую цифру по отдельности

Comment: @Nannik благодарю за указание конкретной ошибки) Дубликаты удалил.